# kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type

Tags: android, exception, kotlin, casting, oncreateoptionsmenu

I am trying to initialize custom search tool (3d library ) on menu but I got error.

Here is my code

```
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.base_nav_drawer,menu)
      searchItem= menu?.findItem(R.id.srchbar_menu)!!
            global_search= searchItem.actionView as MaterialSearchBar
       lastsuggestions=ArrayList<String>()
        loadSuggest()
global_search.lastSuggestions=lastsuggestions
        return true
    }
```

Logcat message

```
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar
        at com.example.sg772.foodorder.BaseNavDrawerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(BaseNavDrawerActivity.kt:136)
```

I tried this

```
 global_search= searchItem.actionView as? MaterialSearchBar
```

But it doesnt help
line 136 corresponds to `global_search= searchItem.actionView as MaterialSearchBar`

xml of menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/srchbar_menu"
          android:title="search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          app:actionViewClass="com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Post the menu's xml.

Comment: @forpas  i   added xml of menu

Answer (score 1):

This line make your app crash

```
global_search = searchItem.actionView as MaterialSearchBar
```

Because `searchItem.actionView` always returns `null` and `global_search` type is `MaterialSearchBar` (non-null type). You assign null to a non-null type, that why your app crash.

You can change your code to

```
var global_search: MaterialSearchBar? = null

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.base_nav_drawer,menu)
    searchItem= menu?.findItem(R.id.srchbar_menu)!!
    global_search = searchItem.actionView as MaterialSearchBar?
    lastsuggestions=ArrayList<String>()
    loadSuggest()
    global_search.lastSuggestions=lastsuggestions
    return true
}
```

But the search view does not show on your app, it seems 3rd party does not support to integrate into a menu item by using `app:actionViewClass`.

Here is a workaround solution that you can try.

https://github.com/mancj/MaterialSearchBar/issues/107

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your actionView member is null and you might want to use:

```
global_search= searchItem.actionView as MaterialSearchBar?
```

or in definition something like this:

```
var global_search:MaterialSearchBar?= searchItem.actionView
```

PS. It would be beneficial if you show how global_search was defined

Comment: var global_search:MaterialSearchBar?= searchItem.actionView  i have type mismatch requerd MaterialSearchBar found View!

Answer (score 0):

if this doesn't help
`global_search= searchItem.actionView as? MaterialSearchBar`

`global_search` is probably declared as Non-Nullable

Make sure it is
`var global_search: MaterialSearchBar? = null`